# How to disable Active x controller unsafe popup while open url in chrome from IE browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, activexobject

I have a requirement to launch our application url in chrome browser from IE browser and found that below code does that job , but while executing below code getting Active x controller unsafe popup with yes or no question . I need to launch in chrome without getting that popup so can any one provide good solution to disable that pop up or any other option to open in chrome browser from IE .

```
  var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  shell.run("Chrome http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Other than change the browser settings manually... nothing.

Comment: ok ,  will it cause any security issue

Comment: Active X itself is a security issue, as it's capable to perform OS operations, which definitely should not be reachable by web sites. If this is intranet stuff, you can ask the administrator to add the app to the trusted pages list in the company's policy. Asking to disable the warning with JS is the same as you've asked how to take the money out of users' bank accounts without their permission.

Answer (score 0):

If possible for you then you can try to make a test to launch the chrome browser using Custom Protocol Handler.

For that you need to create a registry file (any_name.reg) with content below.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeHTML]
@=”Chrome HTML Document”
“URL Protocol”=””
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeHTML\DefaultIcon]
@=”C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe,0″
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeHTML\shell]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeHTML\shell\open]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command]
@=”\”C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\Chrome.exe\” — %1″
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ProtocolExecute\ChromeHTML]
“WarnOnOpen”=dword:00000000
```

Run this registry file to create registry entries.

You can try to create the link like below.

```
<a href="ChromeHTML:// example.com/">Test link</a>
```

Reference:

[How To Launch A URL In Google Chrome](https://www.adamfowlerit.com/2015/05/how-to-launch-a-url-in-google-chrome/)